# How to avoid level of recursion of a circular relationship using Dozer

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, recursion, dozer

As exposed in these question
[How to specify limit or level of recursion of a circular relationship using Dozer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690934/how-to-specify-limit-or-level-of-recursion-of-a-circular-relationship-using-doze)
one strategy to handle this situation is :

Before invoking Dozer loop through your data model to trigger lazy loading until the depth you need. Then use proxy handling feature of Dozer, so it would unwrap the object and do not trigger lazy loading any further (http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/proxyhandling.html). There is a proxy handler for Hibernate, if you are using Eclipse Link or something else you have to write your own.

Does anyone have any example of MapperAware recursive custom converter? I have searched the internet without finding anything.